# Running assembleFlavorDebug on Github actions

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, github-actions

I have an android project with multiple modules which are on different repositories on github.
For debug build we connect the modules with the app locally. For release build we are using jitPack to include them as dependencies.
I want to create a debug build through github actions with the local code which is updated on my machine while it is on different repositories on github.
Is there any way to achieve it.

My structure for debug goes like this.

```
My App
+ Local module 1
+ Local module 2
```

I tried using includeBuild("repo url", "branch name")
But it didn't go as expected